# wsimport giving parse error

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I am getting strange parsing error when I try to import a WSDL using `wsimport`.

Error:-

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid WSDL file: expected 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions found definitions at line 1)
```

I checked the WSDL and I am also surprised the first element of it is not

```
<wsdl:definitions ...>
```

But rather:

```
<definitions   xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" ...>
```

Could this be the problem? The web service is external, so I dont have any control over the WSDL. One thing I know is that it is generated by JAX-WS 2.1.5. Is it a customized WSDL that my wsimport tool is not able to understand? If yes please tell me how to resolve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this conversation](http://forums.java.net/node/700011), the 2.1.5 version of JAX-WS might have generated an incorrect WSDL and you are using wsimport from a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Attila. I switch to jdk1.6.0_04 (from jdk1.6.0_31) and I am getting different error now                                                     expected "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment

Comment: New error :- expected [link](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/) definitions found [link](https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/) definitions at (lineLine number = 1

Comment: I am sorry , somehow I am not able to format the text. But the problem is - WSDL is accessible by https and I have certificates installed in the jre\lib  but wsimport not able to resolve the scema location, Thanks for helping me

Comment: I don't think I can help you with that one.  You could post another question describing your new situation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have following part in the first line of the wsdl?

```
<definitions   ...   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

If not, add it and it should be fine. 
Reason would be, that the namespace declaration for the wsdl is missing.