# Not able to generate web service client using wsgen

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsimport

The original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537471/wsimport-giving-parsing-error/10537686#10537686)

I have a third party web service which is created by Jax WS 2.1.5 and exposed as a HTTPS service (WSDL :- https://somedomain.com/location/soap/locationfinderservice?wsdl)
I am trying to create a client using wsimport. I am using jdk1.6.0_04 for compatibility (I switched JDK version that I have explained in my previous post) Now I am getting new error

```
 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid WSDL expected {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions found   {https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions at (lineLine number = 1
```

The problem is https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ does not exists. How to generate client stubs in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the Wsdl via http rather than https?

If not, grab the Wsdl using a browser and save it locally, then modify it slightly to correct it. Then point wsimport at your tweaked Wsdl file.

The slight modification to apply: locate the namespace declaration at the top of the document (probably looks something like `xmlns:wsdl="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"`) and change to `xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`" (note the http instead of https).